# Security implications of executing strings using eval in bash

Tags: bash, security, eval

Consider the following:

```
$ a='friend'
$ b='printf "%s\n" "$a"'
$ eval "$b"
friend
```

This should be completely safe. Let's however say that `$b` is the same but `$a` is unknown. Are there any security implications then to `eval "$b"` and if so, what can I do to mitigate them?

Comment: It can be safe as long as the string being `eval`ed is fixed (as it is here), but in that case why bother with `eval`? On the other hand, if the string is constructed dynamically, you need to take care to constrain how it's constructed to make sure it's safe.

Comment: @GordonDavisson My thinking is, since I printf the dynamic string then it should be safe regardless of what it contains. Am I wrong in this?

Comment: @GordonDavisson In my specific case I expect `$a` to contain a url. I wish to process the contents of the page the url points to using a sequence piped operations stored in an array like so: `temp= ; for c in ${array[@]}"; do temp=$( printf "$temp" | eval "$c" ); done`

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311507/why-are-eval-like-features-considered-evil-in-contrast-to-other-possibly-harmfu

Comment: `a='"; echo "hi'` is a negative example.

Comment: @waltinator I don't understand. `eval "$b"` just prints `"; echo "hi`. I can see how `eval "$a"` is dangerous though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `b` contains the literal string `printf "%s\n" "$a"`, i.e. you didn't expand `$a` into it before hand, then yes, `eval "$b"` should be fine. Not sure why you'd need `eval` there, though, since you just have a static command. Just run `printf "%s\n" "$a"` directly.

You said in comments you want to store some commands for future use. That's the job of functions. E.g. that `printf` command could be made into a function like this:

```
println() {
    printf "%s\n" "$1"
}
```

which you run as `println "hello there"`, `println "$a"` or whatever. `"$1"` is the first argument to the function, but of course you could read stdin instead, or use multiple arguments (`"$2"`, `"$3"`, ...; or all of them as a list `"$@"` (alike `"${array[@]}"`)).

Similarly for the longer set of operations:

```
#!/bin/bash
say_hi() {
    echo "hello, $1"
}
louder() {
    echo "$1!"
}
funcs=(say_hi louder)
names=(Huey Dewey Louie)
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
    tmp=$name
    for func in "${funcs[@]}"; do
        tmp=$($func "$tmp")
    done
    echo "result: $tmp"
done
```

Comment: This way of calling functions is what I need. I was looking for a way out of using a humongous case statement.